# Nagios check_snmp (New Response) CRITICAL 7

Tags: linux, nagios, alert, check-snmp

I have got a new critical figure / output as 7

SNMP CRITICAL - *7*

What does above 7 refer to?

Answer (score 1):

It's the value of the SNMP variable that you are querying. So, you might set a warning on CPU load above a certain percentage, or disk space below the same. For other variables, it might be some sort of enumerated type.  What exactly it is in your case, you'ld have to look at the command definition to see what OID you are querying.

When you've found out, you might want to add a --label option.